# Need assistance with the way Cordova is naming and/or displaying app name

Tags: java, ios, xcode, cordova

I have an app developed in Cordova that I am having an issue with the way it names my app. My package name is like this "com.companyname.PolarisSearch". The app name should be Polaris Search. When is run, the app shows up as PolarisSearch on iOS. For some reason, the space is just deleted. I can rename my app the ANYTHING other than Polaris Search, and the space shows up just fine. It is just if the name matches the last part of the package name. This is all on Mac OS using Xcode. Does anyone know of a work around for this or how to fix this issue without renaming my package as it has already been submitted and approved on the App Store.

I have tried so far the following:

Removing the iOS build and re-adding it.
Using the plugin cordova-plugin-app-name
Creating a new app and starting from scratch with same package name and app name.

Every time, it will delete that space from the name.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused. The package name is not the app name. Your package is `com.companyname.PolarisSearch` but the name of your app will be set in your config.xml

```
 <name>Polaris Search</name>
```

Just edit your config.xml name node. Alternatively, you could locate in the `info.pList` file

```
 CFBundleDisplayName
```

And set the value to

```
 Polaris\U2007Search
```

Comment: Yeah, that is where I set it at. But, when it is installed, on the Home Screen, it shows as PolarisSearch. I can not get it to keep the space in there.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a work around

Comment: This does seem to work but it also appears that it puts two spaces between the name. Any way to achieve this with only 1 space?

Comment: You could try Polaris\U0020Search